# Views display 0 items

Tags: 7, views

I got to be missing something obvious. I want to display in my view 0 items until they use the Filter Criteria exposed filter with a search parameter.

Under Pager Use Pager I can't see how to display 0 items?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting for this.

Advanced > Exposed form > "Basic"

If the view is still on default, it will be set to Basic, click basic and change it to "Input Required"